# Make smartphone viewport zoom to page width with responsive design

Tags: media-queries, viewport

I have a design that uses media queries, but the media queries only go down to tablet size (i.e. they don't go all the way to 320px for smart phones.

Since I am using width=device-width, smart phones show the page zoomed in.

Should I set width=768px (the smallest size that my media queries go down to)?

Will this mess up the view on tablets that have resolutions larger that 768px wide?

Answer (score 0):

Media queries can do down to even 10px (No real limits on the ability)

Try setting the meta-tag like the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width />
```

See if this solves your problem. It would help if you can provide some code to help us answer better. There is only so much we can understand from just statements.